# No hot water in house unless you run the shower upstairs then you get hot water in the kitchen sink

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

About a month ago we noticed the our shower (which is upstairs) started giving only Luke warm water.  It is now ice cold. We are also not getting hot water elsewhere in the house. We discovered when we run either showers the kitchen sink water can run really hot water. We are not sure what the issue is.

Comment: How does you water heating system work? Is it for example a tankless on-demand system? If a tank, how old is it? Any recent changes to the water plumbing anywhere in the house? If you have a system that mixes hot and cold water the mixing part (in shower?) might be broken and not allowing enough hot water to flow and be mixed in, but the hot water can make it as far as the kitchen sink.

Comment: How old is the shower valve? If not too old (IE before automatic mixing valves), but old enough to fail, it's probably a bad mixing valve.   The other thing, completely different, is if you have a tankless water heater, it's flow detector might be failing, causing it not to fire unless there is a very high flow rate.   If tankless, first thing to check is to turn on the shower and see if the water heater turns on.  Feel the hot water out pipe and see if it's hot.   Do faucets in the bathroom have hot water? Or does only the shower not have hot water?